# Weird java return statements

Tags: java, return

Hi i have recently encountered a weird return statement in this piece of sample code where ClassA is an abstract class.

```
public ClassA getClassA()
{
  ClassA A = new ClassB("some value");
  return (A);
}
```

why is there a bracket around the A variable? Does it signify anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the parentheses don't mean something. It is the same to do:

```
return A;
```

or

```
return (A);
```

Parentheses in Java are good for casting and order of operations in math or Boolean logic. Since you are not doing any of those, the parentheses don't matter.